# Google sheets Extracting Data

Tags: google-sheets

I want to extract cell value but I don't want the value in the brackets. What function should I use?

i.e - Cell value is **Eggs, Milk, Tree Nuts (Almonds, Coconut)** and I want it to be only **Eggs, Milk, Tree Nuts**

Answer (score 0):

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "\(.+\)", "")
```

**Upd.**
For

> Fish(Salmon),Milk(Cheese), Tree Nuts (Almonds, Coconut):

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "\((.+?)\)", "")
```

Comment: thank you. It worked perfectly for that instance. I had another question similar like this one. What if the data looks like this Fish(Salmon),Milk(Cheese), Tree Nuts (Almonds, Coconut)?

Comment: Glad I answered your question
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers